# SQL Server Multi User

Tags: sql-server

I would like to find out on how to go about the issues below:

if we link our MS Access frontend to a SQL Server backend for table storage (for sure with VBA code less DSN file), do we need to do something to ensure that the same multi-user environment continues like in MS Access?

Some people told me that it's not sufficient to have only linked table to MS Access without making SQL Server accept multi users, otherwise it will remain single user.

If this is true how do you switch it on from a single user to multi user?

Comment: Multi user is the default for SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server, like all decent general RDBMSes, is concurrent by design. It is possible to explicitly switch a database to single-user mode for maintenance purposes, but this is an occasional operation and not the default.